# Telethon: where does it store the credentials?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am using [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) to connect to telegram API, and now after development I need to change project api to the main account. I am wondering where the credentials are stored by telethon so I can remove them and force re-authentication?

Comment: @Lonami maybe you know the answer?

Comment: in the same project folder, you can find the file with session_id.session.
like if you `InteractiveTelegramClient('tele_session', '+365000000',api_id=12345, api_hash='abcedfghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890')` . in that tele_session is your session id , so file name should be tele_session.session.

Comment: @SivaSakthiVelan I tried renaming the file to  tele_session.session.old but still the session is logged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass a `str` as the session name, it will create a `str.session` file on the same directory on which you ran your script. So, if you ever change the string you pass to the `TelegramClient` constructor for a non-existing-yet one, it won't be able to login. In the same way, renaming or deleting that session would also work to get rid of that session. You shouldn't delete the session files manually, but rather call `.log_out()`.

Although not related to the question itself, you're also free to override the `Session` class to add custom `.save()` and `.load()` functionality. [This issue](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/16) shows when the format was changed from Pickle to JSON, and [this one](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/16) suggested the ability to actually override the [`Session`](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/tl/session.py) class. For instance:

```
from telethon.tl import Session

class MySession(Session):
    pass  # Override load and save as you wish here
```

Note that currently a migration from `Session` to `JsonSession` is being made, and eventually `JsonSession` will replace the `Session` (as of `v0.10.1`), although this shouldn't affect you if you override the save and load.

Comment: the log_out() method worked fine. thanks. So far I was running client and logging out ;)

Comment: by the way I am noticing when I get an error, the next time running after fixing the bug it outputs the same error, and I need to run again for a fresh run. Is it related to the session and might be fixed with that json change?

Comment: @apadana `.connect()` should return `False` if such error happens, but yes, it will happen on the next run at least once. You must try to `.connect()` again until it returns `True`.